# Issue in triggering Slick Function

Tags: javascript

I am facing an issue in slick function.
There are two tabs, inside that i have created carousel dynamically. For the first tab,slick function is triggered on ready function but for the second tab, i have set a timeout function. On click of the second tab, carousel is dynamically created. 
below is the function used,

function renderSlick() {

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('.item2').slick({
        dots: false,
        arrows: true,
        swipe: true,

        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: false,
        infinite: false,
        variableWidth: true,

    });
}, 200);$(".item2 > .slick-next").on('click', '#challenge-second-div', function () {
    console.log(4)

});
```

in this, slick next is not getting triggered. It is not going inside this click function. Please do suggest some solution.